# Django mail_admins vs send_mail

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-email

I can get my django application to properly report server  errors by email using the obvious settings :

```
DEBUG = False

ADMINS = (('name','email'),)
MANAGERS = (('name','email'),)

EMAIL_HOST = 'ip address'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pwd'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'server-email'
```

Yet for some reason, when I try to use `send_email()` it returns either Authentication errors if I try without TLS, or "You don't have permission to send as this sender" if I do use TLS. I can't understand why error reporting works, and `send_email` doesn't... it uses the same settings by default.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two settings which affect the 'from' email address for different types of emails.

- [`SERVER_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-SERVER_EMAIL) - used for sending error emails to ADMINS and MANAGERS.
- [`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL) - used for sending regular emails

It looks as if you have already set `SERVER_EMAIL`, so make sure you have set `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` as well.